# How to validate the request body if the body is a single json array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to validate the body of the request using the `express-validator`.The hole body is a single array, so i don't have a field name.

I am using the new API of `express-validator` and `express` version 4.

The body looks like this:

```
["item1","item2"]
```

My code:

```
app.post('/mars/:Id/Id', [
    check('id')
        .isLength({  max: 10 })

    .body() //try many ways to get the body. most examples i found were for the old api
    .custom((item) => Array.isArray(item))
],
    (req, res, next) => {           
       const data: string = matchedData(req); //using this method to only pass validated data to the business layer
       return controller.mars(data); //id goes in data.id. i expect there should be an data.body once the body is validated too.
    }
```

How do i validate the body?

Comment: What schema validation is being used by the [tag:express-validator]? I am guessing that if it uses json-schema then you could just validate like `schema = { type: 'array', items: { type: 'string' } }`. A libary for schema validation could be [tiny validator](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4), which is also used by postman for example

Comment: I did not set a json-schema. i will try to use the schema as you say.Take in account that  it is my first time using express-validator.

Comment: Doesn't work. it says: "A validator with name type doesn't exist"

Comment: It seams not supported. i created an issue for improvement at https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/issues/520

Comment: @ByteArtisan Are using ajax to post your data ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using ajax, try to put your array inside an object like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { arr: ["item1", "item2"] },
    success: function (data) {
        // process data here
    }
});
```

Now you could use `arr` identifier to apply validation rules:

```
const { check, body, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

...

app.post('/mars/:Id/Id', [
    check('chatId').isLength({  max: 10 }),
    body('arr').custom((item) => Array.isArray(item))
], (req, res, next) => {           
       const data: string = matchedData(req); 
       return controller.mars(data); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i did that following the instructions from the docs, here is the code:
just declare the custom validator after the expressValidator reference in your code.

```
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(expressValidator({
    customValidators: {
        isArray: function(value) {
            return Array.isArray(value);
        }
    }
}));
```

after that you can check the validity like that:

```
req.checkBody('title', 'title é obrigatório').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('media','media must be an array').isArray();
```

i was using the version 3.2.0 in my project that i could acheive this behavior.
Here is an example of my request body:
    exports.validateAddArrayItem = function(req, res, next) {
    {
    title: 'foo',
    media: [1,2,3]
    }

Aditionally if you do not want to change your response i once did a validation like that:

```
if (req.body.constructor === Array) {
        req.body[0].employee_fk = tk.employee_id;
    }
    req.assert('item', 'The body from request must be an array').isArray();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        var response = { errors: [] };
        errors.forEach(function(err) {
            response.errors.push(err.msg);
        });
        return res.status(400).json(response);
    }
    return next();
};
```

here is an example of my request body:

```
[{
employeefk: 1,
item: 4
}]
```